# Git Changes indicator does not appear in VSCode

Tags: flutter, git, dart, visual-studio-code

Git Changes indicator does not appear in VSCode

[image]

It was supposed to appear like this

[image]

Any Solution?

Comment: @user yeah I get it, I'll track this issue there, thank you

Comment: same issue with me also.